# Cannot transform XML "stylesheet does not contain a document element" (works everywhere but delphi)

Tags: delphi, xslt, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have an XSL file that works fine in every place I have tried it, except in Delphi.  Works for web parsers (e.g. https://xslttest.appspot.com/) and when using `msxsl.exe` from Microsoft.

However, the code below gives the exception when calling `transformNode()` in Delphi 10.2:

> The stylesheet does not contain a document element.  The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document.

From what I understand, this should be using the same MSXML that `msxsl` uses?

```pascal
uses
  Winapi.MSXML;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  transformstring: string;
  xmldoc, xsldoc: IXMLDOMDocument3;
begin

  xmldoc := CoDOMDocument60.Create;
  xsldoc := CoDOMDocument60.Create;

  xmldoc.load('C:\Temp\Data.xml');
  xsldoc.load('C:\Temp\Stylesheet.xsl');
  xsldoc.setProperty('AllowXsltScript', True);

  transformstring := xmldoc.transformNode(xsldoc);
end;
```

XSL file is (this has been minimized):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:param name="D2DSeverityFilter">^Caution^Minor^Moderate^Severe^</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="D2HSeverityFilter">^Extreme Caution^Contraindication^Contraindicated^</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="DocumentationFilter">^Not Established^Limited^Good^Well Established^</xsl:param>
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The input data does not appear to be relevant, but for completeness this empty file will work:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<Result ></Result>
```

The fixed code is below, including the extra properties that needed setting.

```
uses
  Winapi.MSXML;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  transformstring: string;
  xmldoc, xsldoc: IXMLDOMDocument3;
begin

  xmldoc := CoDOMDocument60.Create;
  xsldoc := CoDOMDocument60.Create;

  xmldoc.load('C:\Temp\Data.xml');

  xsldoc.setProperty('AllowXsltScript', True);
  xsldoc.setProperty('ProhibitDTD', False);
  xsldoc.setProperty('ValidateOnParse', False);
  xsldoc.load('C:\Temp\Stylesheet.xsl');

  transformstring := xmldoc.transformNode(xsldoc);
end;
```

Comment: Your Delphi code is using MSXML directly, so any error would have to be coming from Microsoft, not from Delphi. Have you tried removing the whitespace between the `<!DOCTYPE>` and `<xsl:stylesheet>` elements in the XSL file?

Comment: Removing whitespace does not change anything.  My assumption was also that the error was coming from MSXML, but the msxsl.exe I also tried uses it as well so why the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different versions of MSXML, your Delphi code seems to try to use MSXML 6. I think it has, for security reasons, different default settings for various properties, one of them being related to DTDs. So, given your XSLT sample trying to use a DTD, I think you need to allow it explicitly, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762632%28v%3dvs.85%29.

Therefore I think setting `xsldoc.setProperty('ProhibitDTD', False)` **before** the `load` call should help.

Additionally, as we have sorted out in the comments section, the use of the DTD together with MSXML 6 default setting to try to validate a document parsed by the `load` call prevents your stylesheet from being processed, as that DTD snippet obviously doesn't specify the full grammar for an XSLT stylesheet. Thus, you need to set

```
xsldoc.setProperty('ValidateOnParse', False)
```

too.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not change anything, same error.  I also tried with CoDOMDocument30 and IXMLDOMDocument2 and with CoDOMDocument  IXMLDOMDocument also no change.

Comment: Can you check/debug the value of `xsldoc.parseError.errorCode` and `xsldoc.parseError.reason` after the load call?

Comment: xsldoc.parseError.reason = 'The element ''{xsl}stylesheet'' is used but not declared in the DTD/Schema.'
xsldoc.parseError.errorCode = -1072898035

Comment: Then try to set `xsldoc.setProperty('ValidateOnParse', False)` before the `load` call.